# Can't use g++ compiler

Tags: c++, g++

I tried to do this:

```
$ g++
The program 'g++' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install g++
$ sudo apt-get install g++
[sudo] password for user: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
g++ is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Does `sudo apt-get install --reinstall g++` help?

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy g++; dpkg -l g++; echo $PATH`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This probably indicates that you have installed `g++` and then at some point manually removed the actual g++ binary or its symbolic link.

You can force re-install (including re-creating symlinks) by running apt-get install with the `--reinstall` option:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall g++
```